# QGIS crashed when exporting from map layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts, layout-manager

I am a self-taught QGIS user, and I am making a map of the nature preserve where I work. I was practically finished with the whole project when I ran into this problem. Every time I go to export the map, the program crashes. Throughout the project, I have been frequently exporting from the map layout and haven't had a problem. Here is a list of things I have done to try to troubleshoot that resulted in crashing:

- using a new profile
- tried exporting as a PDF, image, and SVG
- trying different map layout templates
- taking off different layers to see if a particular layer is the problem
- updating the software (now using 3.34.4-Prizren)
- Restarting the computer and software

I have successfully exported other map projects which leads me to believe that something is wrong with the map I am working with.

Comment: Please provide relevant error messages, or indicate the lack thereof. Furthermore, provide some details on the number of layers and features within the map items of your layout, as well as other unusual items.

Comment: I learned how to use Python to get this information. There are 57 active layers and 638 features on active layers. No error message appears when crashing. The data types used in this project are wms, gdal,ogr, arcgismapserver and memory.

Comment: Could you also provide information on the version you use and the OS?

Comment: I am using 3.34.4-Prizren on mac.